# Selecting row based on column value in duplicated entries on different column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

This is the df example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'Test':[0,0,1,2,3,2], 'Name':['ID stored','ID stored', 'ID not stored', 'ID not stored', 'ID not stored', 'ID stored']})
```

---

```
   ID           Name  Test
0   1      ID stored     0
1   2      ID stored     0
2   2  ID not stored     1
3   2  ID not stored     2
4   3  ID not stored     3
5   3      ID stored     2
```

What I would like to achieve is to remove the duplicate values based on the column `Name` only resulting in the rows that have the value `ID Stored` in this column.

This is the end result:

```
    ID     Name          Test
0   1      ID stored     0
1   2      ID stored     0
5   3      ID stored     2
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, you're asking to filter here rather than remove duplicated entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ID stored'].drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last'))
   ID       Name  Test
0   1  ID stored     0
1   2  ID stored     0
5   3  ID stored     2
```

Better sample of `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
                  'Test':[0,0,1,2,3,4],
                   'Name':['ID stored','ID stored', 'ID not stored', 
                           'ID stored', 'ID not stored', 'ID stored']})
print (df)
   ID           Name  Test
0   1      ID stored     0
1   2      ID stored     0
2   2  ID not stored     1
3   2      ID stored     2
4   3  ID not stored     3
5   3      ID stored     4

print (df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ID stored'])
   ID       Name  Test
0   1  ID stored     0
1   2  ID stored     0 <-duplicate ID 2
3   2  ID stored     2 <-duplicate ID 2
5   3  ID stored     4

print (df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ID stored'].drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last'))
   ID       Name  Test
0   1  ID stored     0
3   2  ID stored     2
5   3  ID stored     4
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not asking to drop duplicates, rather to filter:

```
In [24]:
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ID stored']

Out[24]:
   ID       Name  Test
0   1  ID stored     0
1   2  ID stored     0
5   3  ID stored     2
```

if you want to get the last ID for a specific ID you can `groupby` and call `last`:

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ID stored'].groupby('ID', as_index=False).last()
```

Comment: so it is also possible that the duplicates all have the ID not stored and then the last ID must be selected

Comment: so you want `df.loc[df['Name'] == 'ID stored'].groupby('ID', as_index=False).last()` in that case